# Bulgarian residency

Tags: resident-permit, bulgaria, egyptian-citizens

I am an Egyptian currently in Bulgaria with a "cultural exchange" visa. I want to marry my Bulgarian girlfriend. I don't know where should I go or what will be the procedures? Should we marry here or in Egypt? And can I know the minimum age for marriage because I am 20 and going to be 21 in June? After the marriage, what will be the next step to get residence and how long does it take? I know that these may be many questions but related to one issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should apply for a residence permit according to Article 24.18 of the [Foreigners in the Republic in Bulgaria act](http://www.mfa.bg/uploads/files/Foreigners_in_the_Republic_of_Bulgaria_Act%281%29.pdf).

The minimum age for a marriage is 16, but if one of you is under 18, you will need a permit from a Bulgarian court. You can also merry outside Bulgaria but then you will need to legalize it.